# Why does EF fail to parse expressions that Linq to Sql can parse successfully

Tags: c#, entity-framework

TL;DR; - Why were certain projection and expression parsing features removed in Entity Framework?  If EF is the supported framework going forward, I'm surprised to see features removed.

---

I'm in the middle of a migration from Linq2Sql to Entity Framework, and the main challenges I'm finding are all around Linq to Entities and the Expression Parser.

For example, in Linq To Sql, I can run a query that projects directly to an object's constructor:

```
db.Table.Select(x=>new KeyValuePair<int,string>(x.Id,x.Name)).ToList();
```

However, in EntityFramework, this throws an error: `Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`  Instead I have to do one of the following two options, which either (1) loads the entire entity, and is expensive, or (2) is verbose and not a clean code practice (IMO).

```
1: db.Table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x=>new KeyValuePair<int,string>(x.Id,x.Name))
    .ToList()
2: db.Table
    .Select(x=>new{x.Id, x.Name})
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x=>new KeyValuePair<int,string>(x.Id,x.Name))
    .ToList();
```

I completely understand that EF cannot send C# code to SQL server, but somehow L2S was smart enough to parse the expression, and handle the select on the SQL side, and the projection on the C# side.

Are there any workarounds? I know that LinqKit and AsExpandable() is able to address some of these constraints, but I have yet to find a clean workaround for the problem demondstrated ago.

Comment: As an aside, LINQ to SQL and EF are just very different, certainly under the covers. I know EF is presented as a successor, but don't make the mistake of thinking they share anything -- EF is not a rewrite or upgrade of L2S. As such, don't be surprised that things work differently; someone did not go around making an inventory of features to port or not port to EF, and talking about "removed" features isn't sensible.

Comment: As I recall, L2S was SQL Server only while EF can target multiple RDBMSes. That could account for some of the differences/restrictions.

Comment: only parameterless constructors are supported, as EF won't emulate the logic within non-default object constructors. the most clean workaround for your setup would simply be what you presented as option #2, as this will pull exactly the data you need, just with one conversion step in between.